# Arduino Linking Undefined Reference

Tags: c++, cmake, compiler-errors, arduino, linker-errors

I am trying to create a cmake file for a small Arduino Project.

I have used the output of the Arduino IDE as a starting point to find the required files and commands. Now I am compiling all sources like the Arduino IDE and then I try to link them together.

Creating the executable in CMake:

```
add_executable(${TARGET_NAME} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/buttontest.cpp)

set_target_properties(${TARGET_NAME} PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS "-T${ARDUINO_PACKAGES}/arduino/hardware/samd/1.6.20/variants/mkrwifi1010/linker_scripts/gcc/flash_with_bootloader.ld \
-Wl,-Map,${TARGET_NAME}.ino.map --specs=nano.specs --specs=nosys.specs -mcpu=cortex-m0plus -mthumb -Wl,--cref -Wl,--check-sections \
-Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--unresolved-symbols=report-all -Wl,--warn-common -Wl,--warn-section-align")


target_link_libraries(
    ${TARGET_NAME}
    wiring_digital
    variant 
    uart    
    ...
)
```

When I try to run it, I always get a undefined reference error

```
../libuart.a(Uart.cpp.obj):(.rodata._ZTI4Uart+0x8): undefined reference to `typeinfo for HardwareSerial'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

It seems to me that the linker can’t find something from the sercom library, I compiled, but I don’t understand why.

We found the arduino-cmake repository on github but we can’t use the code as it is meant for boards using AVR controllers and we have to use an ARM processor (Arduino MKR 1010 Wifi).

Any advice regarding the linker error would be very much appreciated! If approach using CMake for Arduino projects has a fundamental flaw, I also would be thankful for other options.

Project structure:

```
project
 |- build/
 |- buttontest/
    |- CMakeLists.txt
    |- src/buttontest.cpp
 |-cmake/MKRWIFI1010_Toolchain.cmake
 |-CMakeLists.txt
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE cmake/MKRWIFI1010_Toolchain.cmake)

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)

project(buttontest)

set (ARDUINO_PACKAGES $ENV{ARDUINO_PACKAGES})

message(STATUS "${ARDUINO_PACKAGES}")

include_directories(
    ${ARDUINO_PACKAGES}/arduino/tools/CMSIS/4.5.0/CMSIS/Include/ 
    ${ARDUINO_PACKAGES}/arduino/tools/CMSIS-Atmel/1.1.0/CMSIS/Device/ATMEL/ 
    ${ARDUINO_PACKAGES}/arduino/hardware/samd/1.6.20/cores/arduino 
    ${ARDUINO_PACKAGES}/arduino/hardware/samd/1.6.20/variants/mkrwifi1010 
)

# Building common files

# Add persistent compile flags here
add_compile_options (-c -g -MMD -DF_CPU=48000000L -DARDUINO=10808 -DARDUINO_SAMD_MKRWIFI1010 -DARDUINO_ARCH_SAMD
-DUSE_ARDUINO_MKR_PIN_LAYOUT -D__SAMD21G18A__ -DUSB_VID=0x2341 -DUSB_PID=0x8054 -DUSBCON "-DUSB_MANUFACTURER=\"Arduino LLC\"" 
"-DUSB_PRODUCT=\"Arduino MKR WiFi 1010\"" -DUSE_BQ24195L_PMIC)

# Add temporal compile flags here
# FIXME: There must be a better way to do this, but anyway, there must be a better way to write an Arduino CMake Script...
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-x assembler-with-cpp")

set_property(SOURCE ${ARDUINO_PACKAGES}/arduino/hardware/samd/1.6.20/cores/arduino/pulse_asm.S PROPERTY LANGUAGE C)
add_library(pulse_asm ${ARDUINO_PACKAGES}/arduino/hardware/samd/1.6.20/cores/arduino/pulse_asm.S)

# Remove temporal compile flags

add_compile_options (-mcpu=cortex-m0plus -mthumb -Os -Wall -Wextra -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -nostdlib 
--param max-inline-insns-single=500 -Wno-expansion-to-defined)

# C Libraries

add_library(winterrupts ${ARDUINO_PACKAGES}/arduino/hardware/samd/1.6.20/cores/arduino/WInterrupts.c)

set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-std=gnu11")

add_library(itoa ${ARDUINO_PACKAGES}/arduino/hardware/samd/1.6.20/cores/arduino/itoa.c)
add_library(wiring_private ${ARDUINO_PACKAGES}/arduino/hardware/samd/1.6.20/cores/arduino/wiring_private.c)
add_library(wiring_digital ${ARDUINO_PACKAGES}/arduino/hardware/samd/1.6.20/cores/arduino/wiring_digital.c)
add_library(cortex_handlers ${ARDUINO_PACKAGES}/arduino/hardware/samd/1.6.20/cores/arduino/cortex_handlers.c)
add_library(wiring_shift ${ARDUINO_PACKAGES}/arduino/hardware/samd/1.6.20/cores/arduino/wiring_shift.c)
add_library(samd21_host ${ARDUINO_PACKAGES}/arduino/hardware/samd/1.6.20/cores/arduino/USB/samd21_host.c)
add_library(pulse ${ARDUINO_PACKAGES}/arduino/hardware/samd/1.6.20/cores/arduino/pulse.c)
add_library(startup ${ARDUINO_PACKAGES}/arduino/hardware/samd/1.6.20/cores/arduino/startup.c)
add_library(delay ${ARDUINO_PACKAGES}/arduino/hardware/samd/1.6.20/cores/arduino/delay.c)
add_library(wiring ${ARDUINO_PACKAGES}/arduino/hardware/samd/1.6.20/cores/arduino/wiring.c)
add_library(dtostrf ${ARDUINO_PACKAGES}/arduino/hardware/samd/1.6.20/cores/arduino/avr/dtostrf.c)
add_library(wiring_analog ${ARDUINO_PACKAGES}/arduino/hardware/samd/1.6.20/cores/arduino/wiring_analog.c)
add_library(hooks ${ARDUINO_PACKAGES}/arduino/hardware/samd/1.6.20/cores/arduino/hooks.c)

set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-std=gnu++11")
# CPP Libraries


add_library(ipaddress ${ARDUINO_PACKAGES}/arduino/hardware/samd/1.6.20/cores/arduino/IPAddress.cpp)
add_library(wmath ${ARDUINO_PACKAGES}/arduino/hardware/samd/1.6.20/cores/arduino/WMath.cpp)
add_library(new ${ARDUINO_PACKAGES}/arduino/hardware/samd/1.6.20/cores/arduino/new.cpp)
add_library(reset ${ARDUINO_PACKAGES}/arduino/hardware/samd/1.6.20/cores/arduino/Reset.cpp)
add_library(sercom ${ARDUINO_PACKAGES}/arduino/hardware/samd/1.6.20/cores/arduino/SERCOM.cpp)
add_library(cdc ${ARDUINO_PACKAGES}/arduino/hardware/samd/1.6.20/cores/arduino/USB/CDC.cpp)
add_library(stream ${ARDUINO_PACKAGES}/arduino/hardware/samd/1.6.20/cores/arduino/Stream.cpp)
add_library(usbcore ${ARDUINO_PACKAGES}/arduino/hardware/samd/1.6.20/cores/arduino/USB/USBCore.cpp)
add_library(print ${ARDUINO_PACKAGES}/arduino/hardware/samd/1.6.20/cores/arduino/Print.cpp)
add_library(tone ${ARDUINO_PACKAGES}/arduino/hardware/samd/1.6.20/cores/arduino/Tone.cpp)
add_library(pluggableusb ${ARDUINO_PACKAGES}/arduino/hardware/samd/1.6.20/cores/arduino/USB/PluggableUSB.cpp)
add_library(wstring ${ARDUINO_PACKAGES}/arduino/hardware/samd/1.6.20/cores/arduino/WString.cpp)
add_library(abi ${ARDUINO_PACKAGES}/arduino/hardware/samd/1.6.20/cores/arduino/abi.cpp )
add_library(uart ${ARDUINO_PACKAGES}/arduino/hardware/samd/1.6.20/cores/arduino/Uart.cpp)
add_library(main ${ARDUINO_PACKAGES}/arduino/hardware/samd/1.6.20/cores/arduino/main.cpp)

add_compile_options(-fno-threadsafe-statics -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions)


add_library(variant ${ARDUINO_PACKAGES}/arduino/hardware/samd/1.6.20/variants/mkrwifi1010/variant.cpp)

add_subdirectory(buttontest)
```

cmake/MKRWIFI1010_Toolchain.cmake:

```
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Generic)

set (ARDUINO_PACKAGES $ENV{ARDUINO_PACKAGES})

set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER   ${ARDUINO_PACKAGES}/arduino/tools/arm-none-eabi-gcc/4.8.3-2014q1/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER ${ARDUINO_PACKAGES}/arduino/tools/arm-none-eabi-gcc/4.8.3-2014q1/bin/arm-none-eabi-g++)
```

buttontest/CMakeLists.txt:

```
set(TARGET_NAME "buttontest")

link_directories(
    ${ARDUINO_PACKAGES}/arduino/tools/CMSIS/4.5.0/CMSIS/Lib/GCC/ 
    {CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} 
    {CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/buttontest)

add_compile_options(-fno-threadsafe-statics -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions)

add_executable(${TARGET_NAME} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/buttontest.cpp)

set_target_properties(${TARGET_NAME} PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS "-T${ARDUINO_PACKAGES}/arduino/hardware/samd/1.6.20/variants/mkrwifi1010/linker_scripts/gcc/flash_with_bootloader.ld \
-Wl,-Map,${TARGET_NAME}.ino.map --specs=nano.specs --specs=nosys.specs -mcpu=cortex-m0plus -mthumb -Wl,--cref -Wl,--check-sections \
-Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--unresolved-symbols=report-all -Wl,--warn-common -Wl,--warn-section-align")

target_link_libraries(
    ${TARGET_NAME} wiring_digital variant sercom uart arm_cortexM0l_math cdc pulse pulse_asm ipaddress
    cortex_handlers print reset stream tone usbcore pluggableusb samd21_host winterrupts wmath wstring
    abi dtostrf startup hooks itoa new wiring delay main sercom wiring_analog wiring_private wiring_shift)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're missing function body definition of one or more virtual member of the HardwareSerial class. Maybe you missed a define, e.g. HAVE_HWSERIAL0?